# assert module: Is it possible to fail if string is found only once?

Tags: ansible, assert

I have some output from a text file on a Windows system (using winrm) that I am parsing. I am trying to make the playbook fail if it does not see the word 'test' more than once.

This is what I have that works just for continuing the playbook if it sees the word 'test' at least one time:

```yaml
- name: "Windows Output | Parse file"
  win_shell: |
    (Get-Content C:\TEST\output.txt)
  register: 'testing_parse'

- name: "File output | verification"
  assert:
    that:
      - "'test' in testing_parse.stdout"
    fail_msg: "Exiting now."
    success_msg: "Proceeding with task."
```

I thought that the following would work and it did not:

```yaml
- name: "File output | verification"
  assert:
    that:
      - "'test' in testing_parse.stdout >= '2'"
    fail_msg: "Exiting now."
    success_msg: "Proceeding with task."
```

How can I fix my `assert` task so that it meets my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

```yaml
- name: "File output | verification"
  vars:
    watch_regex: '(?:^|\W)(test)(?:$|\W)'
  assert:
    that:
      - testing_parse.stdout | regex_findall(watch_regex) | length > 1
    fail_msg: "Exiting now."
    success_msg: "Proceeding with task."
```

## Why the `in` test is not appropriate

### `in` returns a boolean

Let's first see what we get back from the `in` test in several situations

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'test' in my_test }}" \
    -e "my_test='a test'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": true
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'test' in my_test }}" \
    -e "my_test='a test and an other test'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": true
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'test' in my_test }}" \
    -e "my_test='no word we look for'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": false
}
```

As you can see, it will always return a boolean depending on the presence or not of the needle in the haystack.

### `in` does not find words

Note also that `in` is not very good at finding words (since you mentioned that) as demonstrated below:

```
# It will match a substring in a middle of an other word
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'test' in my_test }}" \
    -e my_test="blahtesttoto"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": true
}

# It will not match a word inside an element of a list...
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'test' in my_test }}" \
    -e '{"my_test":["this is", "a test"]}'

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": false
}

# ... but only an exact match of an element of a list
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'test' in my_test }}" \
    -e '{"my_test":["a", "test"]}'

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": true
}
```

### Your expression is wrong anyway

To end with, let's look at your try when you wrote the expression:

```
'test' in testing_parse.stdout >= '2'
```

This means:

1. check if the string `testing_parse.stdout` is lexically superior or equal to the string `'2'`.
2. now check if the string `'test'` is found inside the preceding boolean result.

As you can now guess with the explanation, there is absolutely no chance this will ever return `true`.

## `regex_findall` to the rescue

A way to look for a specific word is to use a regex. The following will look for the `test` word i.e. the `"test"` string preceded and followed by any non-word character (end of line, beginning of line, white space, tab, punctuation....).

```
(?:^|\W)(test)(?:$|\W)
```

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/903175/1003981) for a specific explanation and https://www.regextutorial.org/ for a general resource (I'm not affiliated, you can find others using your favorite search engine).

The [`regex_find_all` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) can return all matches of a regex against a string into a list

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug \
    -a "msg={{ my_test | regex_findall('(?:^|\\W)(test)(?:$|\\W)') }}" \
    -e "my_test='test'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "test"
    ]
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug \
    -a "msg={{ my_test | regex_findall('(?:^|\\W)(test)(?:$|\\W)') }}" \
    -e "my_test='test and an other test but not blahtesttoto yet test'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "test",
        "test",
        "test"
    ]
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug \
    -a "msg={{ my_test | regex_findall('(?:^|\\W)(test)(?:$|\\W)') }}" \
    -e "my_test='notest'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": []
}
```

Once we have that, we only need to count the number of elements in the returned list whith the `length` filter.

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug \
    -a "msg={{ my_test | regex_findall('(?:^|\\W)(test)(?:$|\\W)') | length }}" \
    -e "my_test='test and an other test but not blahtesttoto yet test'"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "3"
}
```

And finally we can fix your `assert` task according to your requirement:

```yaml
- name: "File output | verification"
  vars:
    watch_regex: '(?:^|\W)(test)(?:$|\W)'
  assert:
    that:
      - testing_parse.stdout | regex_findall(watch_regex) | length > 1
    fail_msg: "Exiting now."
    success_msg: "Proceeding with task."
```

Comment: Wow, this is excellent. I think I understand now. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Ah, ok, gotcha...I did so now.